# What is the best practice for drawing polylines with different colors

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to draw polylines, each composed with different number of points and each has its own color.

What is the best practice in this case - how i should gather the information and send it to the GPU?

Comment: You want to draw them in a single draw call ?

Comment: This is basically the question - how i should draw them? In a single call, each polyline in its own glDrawArrays call (this is what i am doing now)

Comment: How about using a small texture with each pixel having one colour per line. Then just add texture coordinates to your vertex data. For instance you create a 128x1 texture, fill the colours and have texture coordinates like (1/128*(0-.5), .5), (1/128*(1-.5), .5), (1/128*(2-.5), .5)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose all your strips into `GL_LINES` and render them with a single `glDrawArrays()`/`glDrawElements()` call.

For the `glDrawElements()` case you can decompose the strips like this:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

struct LineBatch
{
    void AddStrip( const vector< vec2 >& strip, const vec3& color )
    {
        if( strip.size() < 2 )
            return;

        for( size_t i = 1; i < strip.size(); ++i )
        {
            indices.push_back( (GLushort)verts.size() + (GLushort)(i-1) );
            indices.push_back( (GLushort)verts.size() + (GLushort)(i-0) );
        }

        for( size_t i = 0; i < strip.size(); ++i )
        {
            Vertex temp;
            temp.pos = strip[i];
            temp.color = color;
            verts.push_back( temp );
        }
    }

    void Render()
    {
        ...
        glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indices[0] );
        ...
    }

private:
    struct Vertex
    {
        vec2 pos;
        vec3 color;
    };
    vector< Vertex > verts;
    vector< GLushort > indices;
};
```

Comment: This is actually OpenGL ES 2.0, so i believe glMultiDrawElements is not supported.If i will use GL_LINES, i will have to duplicate each vertex than is not one of the polyline edges, no? What do you mean by primitive restart?

Comment: [Primitive restart](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) isn't in ES 2.0 so that's out too.

Comment: You'll have to duplicate vertices for the `glDrawArrays()` case.  For `glDrawElements()` you only have to duplicate the indexes.